# twitch api Get token return "unknow error" Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, twitch

I'm trying to retrieve a token via twitch api but I have an unknown error: "Http failure response for https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token: 0 Unknown Error".

[image: Here is the error]

Here is the request :

```html
let httpParams = new HttpParams()
    .append("client_id", this.cliendID)
    .append("client_secret", this.cliendSecret)
    .append("code", code)
    .append("grant_type", "authorization_code")
    .append("redirect_uri", my_redirect_uri);

    this.http.post("https://id.twitch.tv/oauth2/token", httpParams.toString(), 
    { headers: { 
      'Client-ID': this.cliendID,
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+code,
      'Accept': 'application/json'
    },}).subscribe(data => {     
      console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: `.toString()` is wrong

Comment: Same error without

Comment: But you had to fix it https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#http-request-example